# Angular 5 converting html to pdf

Tags: angular, jspdf, html2canvas, html2pdf, jspdf-autotable

i have a requirement to convert the UI/HTML to PDF, i am using jsPDF & html2canvas and i am to create pdf but in Internet Explorer it is very slow taking nearly 3 minutes to create a 7 pdf.

Please let me know if there is any other plugin  available.

I tried to html2pdf() but the image is not in good order.

Thanks
vinod.

Comment: Might be this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular5-pdf

Comment: I am not using canvas HTML element. I am getting the element using <div>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great plugin for doing this. Let me know if it was helpful.
[ngx-export-as](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-export-as)

Comment: thanks for the reply. It has mentioned there is a issue and it doen't support multiple page rendtion. Have you tried with multiple page.